# babelify 6 with browserify and the es2015 preset is not working

Tags: browserify, babeljs

I am attempting to use the new babel release, and while trying to use the es2015 preset babel doesn't seem to be able to understand arrow functions?

My setup on pre-babel6 was as follows:

```
transform: [['babelify', {sourceMap: false, stage: 0, optional: 'runtime', ignore: ["*.min.js"]}]]
```

and with babel6

```
transform: [['babelify', {"presets": ["es2015"]}]]
```

which does not work. Why is this?

**edit**

adding `"stage-0"` got rid of the syntax error messages, but has stoped me from being able to extend anything with the error: `'this' is not allowed before super()` when I have infact got a `super()` call.

**edit**

Set up a simple test application with some es7 and tried to use the babel-core require hook, same problem.

**edit**

Ok so I have narrowed it down to stage-0 working differently in babeljs 6^.

Here is what I have noticed:

Run file

```
require("babel-core/register")(
    {
        presets: ["es2015", "stage-0"]
    }
);

require("./app.js");
```

Works with:

```
class extendable {
    constructor() {
        console.log('extended')
    }
}

class app extends extendable {

    constructor() {

        super();

        this.method();
        this.method2();
    }

    method() {
        // arrow functions
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("works")
        }, 1000)
    }

    /**
     * arrow function method
     */
    method2 = () => {
        console.log('works')
    }
}
new app();
```

Doesn't work with:

```
class extendable {
    constructor() {
        console.log('extended')
    }
}

class app extends extendable {

    constructor() {

        super();

        this.method();
        this.method2();
    }

    method() {
        // arrow functions
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("works")
        }, 1000)
    }

    /**
     * arrow function method
     */
    method2 = () => {
        // give an error: 'this' is not allowed before super()
        this.state = "hello";
    }
}
new app();
```

So I am a little confused. Is this really incorrect syntax? How have I been able to use this pre-babel6?

Comment: How are you executing browserify/babelify? What versions of the modules do you have installed?

Comment: I am executing through [module-deps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-deps), everything is at its latest version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a Babeljs bug

See

- [Subclasses with class properties (without constructor) error #2942](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2942)
- [[Regression BUG] Class scoped function showing SyntaxError: 'this' is not allowed before super() #2971](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2971)

Hopefully this will see a fast fix.

**edit** #2942 is not referencing the same bug. Here is an issue following this bug: [#3028](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/3028)

Comment: #2942 is closed and they say 6.1.18 is fixed. Just npm updated and added the arrow function. Still broke. Thats with babelify if it makes a diff.

Comment: Same here, I'm still getting all sorts of errors with Babel6 supposedly fixed bugs, trying to restructure my classes which were perfectly fine in 5,...kind of getting tired.

Comment: I am going to test and see if I can still reproduce the error. But coming from their blog: "Not all integrations have been updated yet. This is a very disruptive major so please bear with us as we smooth out the edges." So I would suggest sticking with 5 until the majority of the bug have been fixed

Comment: I can confirm this is not fixed

Comment: Having this problem too, and the links to the issues are all dead now

Comment: I would suggest opening an issue with babelify.

Answer (score 5):

It depends a bit on how you are executing browserify, this is what the Github repository from babelify (https://github.com/babel/babelify) says about it :

**From the CLI:**

```
$ browserify script.js -o bundle.js \
-t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ]
```

**With Node:**

```
browserify("./script.js")
  .transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2015", "react"]})
  .bundle()
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("bundle.js"));
```

Comment: `transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2015", "react"]})` is what is not working

Comment: Have you installed the presets? `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015`

Comment: Presets with gulp didn't seem to work at all. Its frustrating how frequently everything changes. One version of babelify does one thing and the next version lots of stuff changes..

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the CLI syntax for me!